# How can I skip a required field if is not in the form?

Tags: users, field, frontend, required

The problem is that I have a register page where I have 3 fields, Username, Email, Password. There is another page with some more fields which are required. So when I try to register a user form my register page I get errors about my required fields which I don't have in the register page. How can I skip them form cheking on my register page, but still have them as required on my profile page? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "The problem is that when User try to update the profile and already have a file uploaded."  What's the problem?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Yes, it's saying the field cannot be blank. If I remove the field completly dosnt show error message, but doesnt want to update the other user data. I think is because is cheking some where in the model about this field.

Comment: I edited my question because is not only for asset field at first was but now i face this problem with my other fields

Comment: Can you share the template code you're using for the forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're required, then they're *required*... it doesn't matter if the form is being submitted on the front-end or back-end.

The easiest solution to this would be to simply provide that data as **hidden inputs**...

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[myRequiredField]" value="default value">
```